# Silverlight 3 streaming via future Moonlight version?

Tags: moonlight

I am trying to watch a streaming service that requires Silverlight 3. Although I installed Moonlight and the browser plugin, I just get a warning that since my URL is Silverlight 3, it may not fully work. But I get nothing.

Are there any plans to support Silverlight 3 in future versions of Moonlight?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As a matter of fact, the Silverlight 3 API is considered feature complete in the Moonlight 4 Preview 1 version:

> **Release Notes Moonlight 4 Preview**
>
> Moonlight 4 Preview 1 is the first preview of Moonlight that includes support for the Siverlight 3 APIs and partial support for Silverlight 4 APIs. We consider the Silverlight 3 API support to be feature complete while the Silverlight 4 APIs are both partial and might be missing features.

[From the [release notes](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Moonlight4_Preview).]

You can download it [here](http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/download.aspx). However, it's possible that some sites do stupid system checking based on your user agent - so it might be possible that you technically could view the content, but the site prevents it from being displayed. Just post the site in question.